# filter undesired results from a sql query in PHP

Tags: php, sql

I have a query that returns a list of products. The table cannot be altered to include another column (like a binary `include_in_dropdown`). Assuming That there are indeed some products that I do not want to include in a dropdown that I'm populating with this data (eg, because it is infrequently ordered or is too esoteric and unintuitive to a user of an order form on a webpage) what is the best practice way to not include it in the dropdown I'm populating?

```
while ($row = mssql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    //a switch with a bunch of cases statically 
    //listing the products I don't want to list
    //switch($row[$col_val]){
          //case: "Outsource"
          //break 1;
          //case: "Shipping"
          //break 1;
     //}

     //some other way that is more maintainable(??)

    echo "<tr>";
    foreach ($column_names as $col_key => $col_val){
        echo "<td>";
        echo $row[$col_val];
        echo "</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";
    $count ++;
}
```

I sort of understand that is an incredibly unideal situation and this might be the only way, but maybe there's a better method than a switch statement that's a mile long. Interested in any ideas.

Comment: filter it in the database to begin with? unless the filtering logic would make the query so huge/ugly it'd be unmaintainable, it's generally a good idea to not send data from db->php just to throw it away later.

Comment: @MarcB I will see if this is an option. Maybe I can get one of the unused fields to be set as a flag specifically for me. Can you submit that as an answer so I can give you the check? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Can you modify the query to have something like this?

```
where product not in ('Outsource', 'Shipping', . . .)
```

Doing the filtering in the query is a big advantage . . . it should be faster and reduce the communication between the db and the application.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you can do a complicated query in the db, that is your best option (Like only selecting items that are regularly ordered).
2. Within the while, add a `if(!someExclusionFunction($row)) {` type statement and then put your display logic (echo statements) in there. You then add the `someExclusionFunction` to check the rows. The advantage of this is that it moves your exclusion code out of your display logic.

Given option 2, you can build your `someExclusionFunction` to check a flat file with just a list of products to exclude or use some other arbitrary list or formula.

All in all, think really hard if you can do this in the db query.

Answer (score 0):

Unless the values of a column have some commonality that allows you to decide whether
to exclude/include, you'll need a switch statement or something equivalent. Using [in_array](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php)
is sometimes a little more elegant.

```
$exclude = array(
    "Outsource",
    "Shipping",
    // more options ...
);

while ($row = mssql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    if (in_array($row['column_name'], $exclude)) {
        continue;
    }

    // add to dropdown ...
}
```